# persistence.xml not getting added in ear

Tags: java, maven, ejb-3.0, persistence.xml

We have a maven project with ejbs and stuff. When i run a build and create my ear, the persistence.xml doesnt get included inside the ear. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Do you keep your persistence.xml in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/`?

Comment: yeah Jeremy...that's exactly where i have the file

Comment: That's where I have it too, are you looking inside the ear file itself, or inside the embedded ejb jar file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add you file persistence.xml under **\src\Main\application\META-INF**, then the file will be added under your META-INF folder of your ear.

Regards,